# rule ids from table rules for which item and dc are deactivated

Tags: sql

There are three tables namely rules, settings and dc_activation.
dc_activation has columns as id,item,dc,start_date,end_date, valid.
settings has columns as id,create_date,update_date,setting_type,sequence,name and value.
Rules has columns as id,item,dc,name,start_date,valid.
We want to get rule ids from table rules for which item and dc are deactivated.
Note: Item and Dc are deactivated when end_date< value corresponding to v_date.
v_date is an entry in the column name in table settings and holds a value corresponding to it.
Require an SQL query for the same.

Comment: Hello, please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not how SO works.  It is not a free coding service.  You need to show some effort. 
 Read [ask] and post a [mcve].  Also take some time to format your question so that it is readable.  Provide the table definitions and sample data, and tag question with the db platform.  thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.